# Nuxt3: `useRequestEvent()` return undefined in server plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I want to access `header.node.req._parsedUrl` but it's return undefined. Anyone know what's the solution.

Here's the code

```js
// plugins/init.server.ts

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const header = useRequestEvent();
  console.log(header.node.req._parsedUrl);
});
```